# Is beer a davar charif?

Tags: halacha, meat-and-milk, liquor-beer

I recently brewed beer in a meat non-Ben-Yomo  pot. Is beer considered a davar charif rendering my beer impermissible to be consumed with dairy? Would it depend on how much hops were used? Are only sharp things (garlic, onions, etc.) davar charif, or also very bitter things (lemons, hops, etc.)?

Comment: I don't know what hops really are, but it definitely extends to bitter things like lemons.  Rabbi Forst lists whisky and olive oil.  Not beer though.

Comment: Are lemons bitter? I think of radicchio and bad cucumbers as bitter, but lemons as sour.

Comment: impermissible to be consumed **with** dairy is only for askenazim

Comment: Some thoughts about this that may help someone else form an answer. there are some forms of beer which have vinegar like characteristics as a result of acetic acid but those characteristics would not be present in making the wort but develop in the fermenter if certain yeasts post fermentation are exposed to too much oxygen. Not all hops have the same level of bittering effect. Some hops which are high in alpha acids can have a high level of bittering impact but only depending on what time frame they are added to the boil.

Comment: For example in a standard 60 minute boil hops added in the beginning would be the most bitter and those added from 15 minutes onward would contribute more to aroma.

Comment: I have this same question but with a pot that was ben yomo...

Answer (score 1):

No, beer is not a "davar charif." Hops are somewhat bitter, I suppose you could potentially argue if they're called charif, but the overall product, beer, is not *that* pungent. (Similarly, some out there treat *mayonnaise* as *davar charif* because one of the ingredients on the label is lemon juice! But the product mayonnaise is not sharp-tasting! My father asked R' Shimon Eider zt"l about this, who concurred that mayo is absolutely not a davar charif.

Comment: How about India Pale Ale (IPA) these beers are quite hoppy. Are you familiar with them?

Comment: I still don't hear it.

Comment: See Mishbatzos Zhav at the end of Siman 104 that beer is not like vinager

Comment: But mayo contains vinegar which is a d'var charif. Isn't that a problem?

Comment: so if vinegar is a davar chariff then would a beer that has acitic acid in it be a davar chariff such as a flanders red?

Comment: @Laser123 I still don't hear it. It's about the overall acidity of the product, not its ingredients. The most sour of beers bottom out at a pH of 3.1, while regular vinegar (5% acidity) is 2.4.

Comment: @Shalom can you source the reason for davar chariff is ph level?